# Laravel get highest value of day in database

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to get the day with the highest value from my database.

My database structure looks like this:

```
id | value | date
1    5       2022-02-07 10:00:00
2    9       2022-02-07 11:00:00
3    2       2022-02-07 12:00:00
4    1       2022-02-08 02:00:00
5    2       2022-02-08 09:00:00
6    5       2022-02-09 13:00:00
7    8       2022-02-09 18:00:00
```

What I want to get out:

```
[
   'value' => 16,
   'date' => 2022-02-07
]
```

Normally I would show you some some ideas, but I really have no idea how to do it. If there are millions of entries, I can't just pull the entire query and loop through it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Hope this is table above is a table existing on your database, so you might have a model for it?

Comment: If so things could be so easy

Comment: Yes I have a model for this. Is there an existing Laravel build-in to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we could use:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS sum_val, DATE(date) AS date_group
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY sum_val DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

May be you could need instead:

```
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MyTimestamp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Ansev´s answer, here the Laravel Eloquent version:

```
DB::table('mytable')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(`value`) AS sum_val, DATE(`date`) AS date_group')
    ->groupBy('date_group')
    ->orderByDesc('sum_val')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
```